# .htaccess to redirect domain1 to domain2

Tags: domains, htaccess, mod-rewrite, multiple-domains

I currently have a `.htaccess` file with the current lines to force HTTPS:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

My main domain is `example.com`
I have a registered an alias in my cPanel: `example.net`

I would like to implement a rule so that if a user visits `example.com`, they will be redirected to `https://example.net`.

I've tried a few things and kept getting redirection errors.
Can someone help me out, not sure what I should be doing here?

Comment: What about www and other subdomains?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.net$
RewriteRule .* https://example.net%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

If `HTTPS` is `off` *or* the requested *host* is not `example.net` then redirect to HTTPS and `example.net`.

Comment: Should be `RewriteRule .* https://domain.tech%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

Comment: @user1692517 No, have a look at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html#regex for a clear example on `%` and `$` in `mod_rewrite`, they serve different purposes.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek This isn't a _backreference_ (where you have `%n` and `$n`), it's a reference to a server variable of the form `%{SERVER-VARIABLE}`. I'd made a typo in my answer - now updated.